# How to check if a multiline TextBox contains a string?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Will .equals(textbox.text) work?

Comment: What do you mean by `located inside`? Identical? Or that it is part of the content?

Comment: it is quite easy to try, why don't you do it?

Comment: @William: how about you simply try it out?

Comment: @box86rowh It's **`c#`** not `JavaScript`!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Contains method with string to find out it has some string which you want to search. Equal method if used to check if both strings have same value.

Try this for finding string with in other string.

```
textbox.Text.Contains("string to search");
```